# Issue when adding an admin menu to a WP plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following function which creates the menus in the admin area for my plugin.

```
 function register_menu_items() {

            add_menu_page(null, 'Ebay Motors', 'manage_options', 'ebay-motors-admin', array($this, 'ebay_motors_admin')); 

            add_submenu_page( 'ebay-motors-admin', 'Upload XML', 'Upload XML', 'manage_options', 'upload-xml', array($this, 'upload_xml')); 
            add_submenu_page( 'ebay-motors-admin', 'Archive XML', 'Archive XML', 'manage_options', 'archive_xml', array($this, 'archive_xml'));

}
```

This works, however (expectedly) the main menu item also creates a sub-menu item. Is there a way to create the main menu item without intern creating a submenu item. I'd also like the Main Menu item to link straight to the upload_xml function.

Comment: This would probably be a better question on wordpress.stackexchange.com, but you are using "add_submenu_page" to add a submenu.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the slug of your sub menu to be the same of the main menu item. This way you can overwrite the first menu item.